# How to use a Logger outside of main

Tags: go

I am using logger package [github.com/jcelliott/lumber](https://github.com/jcelliott/lumber) for logging in go, and I declare and use it like this:

```
func main() {
log := lumber.NewConsoleLogger(lumber.DEBUG)
...
log.Error("File error: %v\n", e)
}
```

How can I log from functions outside of main? Obviously here log is declared within main and that limits its scope, but I haven't found a way to have global variables in GO, is there a better way than re-declaring the logger in each function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your global variable like this :

```
var log lumber.Logger

func anyFunc() {
  log.Error("File error: %v\n", e)
}

func main() {
  log = lumber.NewConsoleLogger(lumber.DEBUG)
  anyFunc()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have looked for package variables instead of global variables ;-)